Aligning rasters using native:alignrasters with PyQGIS
I would like to use native:alignrasters to, obviously, align two rasters. However, it does not accept my input layer, despite it being valid.
(I tried native:alignsingleraster as well, but that is even worse in producing rather strange results.)
Metadata of reference layer: \

Extent 457181.0972860999754630,5592492.1701155193150043 : 
461079.9963524600607343,5596154.2149340696632862
Width   390
Height  366
Data type   Byte - Eight bit unsigned integer
GDAL Driver Description netCDF
Dimensions  X: 390 Y: 366 Bands: 1
Origin  457181.0972860999754630,5596154.2149340696632862
Pixel Size  9.997177093230986245,-10.00558693592934212

QGIS Version is 3.34.11

ALIGNING RASTERS ----------
params = {
'LAYERS': [{'layer': pop_warped_layer,
'output': 'memory:pop_aligned',
'resampling': 0}],
'REFERENCE_LAYER': highway_raster_layer
}

# Run the gdal:alignraster algorithm
pop_alligned = processing.run("native:alignrasters", params)
pop_alligned_layer = QgsRasterLayer(pop_alligned[0]['OUTPUT'], 'pop_alligned')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(pop_alligned_layer)

error message:
Unable to execute algorithm
Incorrect parameter value for LAYERS
Execution failed after 73.13 seconds (1 minute 13 seconds)


Please [Edit] the Question to contain metadata from the layers: coordinate references, extents, pixel sizes,...

Your parameter keys for the 'LAYERS' map are incorrect; the keys are 'inputFile' and 'outputFile'. This algorithm works with file inputs and outputs, so if you are working with QgsRasterLayer objects you need to access their .source(). Also the returned result dictionary has no 'OUTPUT' key so trying to load your layer like that will fail.
I take it that you are trying to create a temporary output raster. You can use QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination for that (reference).
If you print the return value of the processing.run() call, it will be something like (depending on os):
{'OUTPUT_LAYERS': ['/tmp/processing_oXKotP/363bcc882a244bacbcee5428a38c91f8/pop_aligned.tif']}

So you could also access the file path like:
pop_alligned_layer = QgsRasterLayer(pop_alligned['OUTPUT_LAYERS'][0], 'pop_alligned')

This snippet assumes that pop_warped_layer and highway_raster_layer are QgsRasterLayer objects.
dest = QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination(name='pop_aligned')
temporary_output = dest.generateTemporaryDestination()

params = {'CELL_SIZE_X': None,
        'CELL_SIZE_Y':None,
        'CRS':None,
        'EXTENT':None,
        'GRID_OFFSET_X':None,
        'GRID_OFFSET_Y':None,
        'LAYERS':[{'inputFile':pop_warped_layer.source(),'outputFile':temporary_output,'resampleMethod': 0,'rescale': False}],
        'REFERENCE_LAYER':highway_raster_layer.source()}
        
processing.run('native:alignrasters', params)
iface.addRasterLayer(temporary_output, 'pop_aligned', 'gdal')

Hint for running processing algorithms via the Python API: run the algorithm via the gui, then click the History button in the toolbar at the top of the Processing toolbox dockwidget. Click the item row to see the syntax of the processing.run() call which was executed.

Thanks again Ben for helping me. Your snippet seems to work, however it produces the same problem as native:alignsingleraster before, namely assigning high positive values (the same for each raster, but different between aligned rasters) to cells that should be Null/NAN
